# carriage return not working in Terminator but works fine in Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: python, carriage-return, terminator

I am using '\r' in print function in python 2.7. It works fine in terminal but not in terminator.

---

**For example:**

I am using a decrement counter which decrements from n to 0. In the Terminal, the count values are updated at the same line while in terminator, it count values get printed on new line. I am using terminator for various reasons such as its advanced features like tab partitioning etc. Below is the code snapshot

```
import sys
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sleep_time_in_sec = 15
    time_to_go_back_mns = 10

    for remaining in range(sleep_time_in_sec, -1, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write(
            "{:2d} seconds remaining to read last {:2d} minutes of data and perform prediction .....".format(remaining,
             time_to_go_back_mns))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Can someone please suggest a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this post goes to @Rick van Lieshout.

---

In my case, I was using multiple tabs in the same window as a result of which \r was not working. It worked fine when I used it in a separate window or a tab with full horizontal width.

Answer (score 3):

Simply place the \r at the end of your write statement like so:

```
sys.stdout.write(
            "{:2d} seconds remaining to read last {:2d} minutes of data and perform prediction .....\r".format(remaining,
             time_to_go_back_mns))
```

New data will then overwrite the line, you can use flush() to clear the line before writing to it again:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Make sure that on the terminator side of things your profile settings are clean. Be sure to check out the compatibility tab as it mentions weird application behaviour.

[image]

**note** that carriage return stops functioning if the terminal size is too small. It will only return to the first character of the LAST line

**Original answer**

`\r` actually means "carriage return" whereas `\n` is a line feed.
In Linux (Unix) you'd usually use either a `\n` or `\r\n`.

So if your goal is to go to a new line you should use `\n` instead.

The reason it might work in the "terminal" (whichever one that might be) is because some terminals (notably gnome's terminal) catches the `\r` and treats it as a `\r\n`.

Comment: @PeterWood I used ''\r\n" but it is printing in the new line. Thaks for your comment anyways.

Comment: I changed my answer after your initial edit :)

\r\n would indeed print it on a new line

Comment: @PeterWood: using ''\r" at end of the line as you suggested is giving the same output. I am using terminator 0.97, does that make any difference

Comment: I have recorded a little clip showing you that it works with the latest version of terminator (1.0): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d494o9K4WA

Must be a client side setting then I guess.

Comment: note that carriage return stops functioning if the terminal size is too small. It will only return to the first character of the LAST line :)

Comment: you are exactly right. This was the issue. I was using 8 tabs in one terminal. But when I tried it on the separate terminal it worked like charm.

Comment: that would do it! Have a great day :)